# PHP and MySQL smallest and largest possible date

Tags: php, mysql, date

What is the largest date PHP and MySQL recognizes?

I mean, I have different values for different timeline and I want to make them all as `BETWEEN` selects in MySQL, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-10-01' AND '2011-10-02';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-10-03' AND '2011-10-10';
```

etc.

To get all options, was thinking of something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '0000-01-01' AND '2011-10-01';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-10-02' AND '2011-10-10';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-10-11' AND '9999-12-31';
```

Will this always work or is there a chance the code might break at some point?

Comment: Yes, but aren't the limits also `1970-01-01` to `2038-01-19` ?

Comment: Instead of a between, why dont you just use a less than and the end date?

Comment: @WayneC What's the difference?

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

Comment: Thank you m8, that was exactly what I was asking for. Was also looking at the documentation, but must have skipped that part somehow.

Comment: @DainisAbols Cool, Google's my companion too... :)

Answer (score 11):

Here is the different date range , depends on your column type:

[As per docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html)

The **DATE type** is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. **The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.**

The **DATETIME type** is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. **The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.**

The **TIMESTAMP data type** is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of **'1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.**

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's `DATETIME` type supports from "1000-01-01" to "9999-12-31". That should be sufficient.

PHP can analyze those as well; they aren't two digit years, so it's good. I just ran strtotime on 9999-01-01 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date < '2011-10-01';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '2011-10-02' AND '2011-10-10';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > '2011-10-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates are nothing more than integers. Integer size are system dependent; i.e. 32 bit, 64 bit, etc.

In php integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX

In mysql you can do something lke this:
          SELECT ~0 as max_bigint_unsigned

Answer (score -2):

Maybe get the max and min values from your table first:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(date) FROM table) AND (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was asking for.