# Scope with ORDER BY CASE clause not working properly

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, named-scope

I have a scope on my rails model that is supposed to help me sort my objects. This is shown below:

```
scope :active, ->(u = nil, now = "NOW()") {
  published_and_private(u).eager_load(:images)
    .where("(listing = 1 AND complete = 0) OR " +                                        # LISTING
         "(online_only = 1 AND scheduled_end_time + INTERVAL 1 DAY >= #{now}) OR " +   # TIMED
         "(online_only = 0 AND listing = 0 AND starts_at + INTERVAL 1 DAY >= #{now})") # LIVE
    .order("complete, CASE WHEN sort_index IS NOT NULL THEN sort_index " +
         "WHEN scheduled_end_time IS NOT NULL THEN scheduled_end_time " +
         "WHEN starts_at IS NOT NULL THEN starts_at ELSE #{now} + INTERVAL 10 YEAR END")
}
```

Below is the data from the database that is returned when the query gets ran:

```
select id, name, complete, sort_index, starts_at, scheduled_end_time from auctions where published = 1 ORDER BY complete, CASE WHEN sort_index IS not NULL THEN sort_index WHEN scheduled_end_time IS NOT NULL THEN scheduled_end_time WHEN starts_at IS NOT NULL THEN starts_at ELSE (NOW() + INTERVAL 10 YEAR) END;


+----+-----------------------------------+----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | name                              | complete | sort_index | starts_at           | scheduled_end_time  |
+----+-----------------------------------+----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 21 | Listing: Mountain Cabin Estate    |        0 |          1 | NULL                | NULL                |
| 17 | Multi-Item Online Only            |        0 |          2 | 2017-08-07 06:48:00 | 2017-08-21 12:48:00 |
|  9 | Multi-item Live Auction           |        0 |       NULL | 2017-08-21 18:48:02 | NULL                |
| 19 | Many Item LIVE Auction            |        0 |       NULL | 2017-08-21 18:48:02 | NULL                |
| 10 | Single Item Online Only           |        0 |       NULL | 2017-08-07 18:48:03 | 2017-08-22 00:48:02 |
| 18 | MANY Item Timed Auction           |        0 |       NULL | 2017-08-07 18:48:03 | 2017-08-22 00:48:02 |
| 22 | LISTING: Multi-parcel Real Estate |        0 |       NULL | NULL                | NULL                |
| 20 | Bad Images                        |        0 |          3 | 2017-08-21 14:48:00 | NULL                |
|  8 | Single Item Live Auction          |        1 |       NULL | 2017-08-21 18:48:02 | NULL                |
+----+-----------------------------------+----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

My problem is that the object with a sort index of 3 is out of place, this happens for any number over 2 and I am at a complete loss as to why this may be. I was expecting the query to place that object right under the one with a sort_index of 2.

Any help, guidance, or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you think about it your order by clause doesn't make much sense. You are mixing integers with dates. How should those be sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to put all of those conditions into a `CASE... WHEN`. `CASE ... WHEN` effectively creates one pseudo-column in your `WHERE` clause. So what you did is no different from:

```
SELECT *, CASE /* your logic */ END AS sort_logic 
/* 
   Notice that the sort_logic column doesn't actually exist in the table. Instead
   MySQL calculates the value and for the duration of this query
*/
WHERE /* <stuff> */
ORDER BY sort_logic
```

What you really want is a series of column values. @Darshan has one approach above, which is basically create a series of boolean columns and add those to the sort:

```
complete, ISNULL(sort_index) DESC, 
          /*
             Desc and ASC are important here. You want NOT NULL values to float to
             the top, but you want the columns to work in ascending order.
          */
          sort_index ASC, 
          ISNULL(scheduled_end_time) DESC, scheduled_end_time ASC, 
          ISNULL(starts_at) DESC, starts_at ASC,
```

You also have the option of defaulting the column values to MySQL max values. In this case `'9999-12-31'` represents the [highest possible date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178858/php-and-mysql-smallest-and-largest-possible-date), and `~0` [represents the max int value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679064/in-sql-how-do-i-get-the-maximum-value-for-an-integer):

```
complete, 
   ISNULL(sort_index, ~0), 
   ISNULL(scheduled_end_time, '9999-12-31'), 
   ISNULL(starts_at, '9999-12-31')
```

In this case, the logic is "Sort by `complete`, if `sort_index` isn't null use that for sorting, otherwise throw the result to the end of the list where `sort_index` isn't null…" and the same logic follows for all of the other columns.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with `ISNULL` instead, e.g.:

```
.order("complete, ISNULL(sort_index), sort_index, " +
         "ISNULL(scheduled_end_time), scheduled_end_time " +
         "ISNULL(starts_at), starts_at")
```

Comment: That's not quite right either. Sort index is right at that point, but then the ones that need to be sorted by time aren't in the right order

Comment: Are you getting nulls first in the sorting for `scheduled_end_time`?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the order clause you're looking for is:

```
order by complete,
         Coalesce(
           sort_index,
           scheduled_end_time,
           starts_at,
           #{now} + INTERVAL 10 YEAR
         )
```

However, you're comparing an integer with dates in this sort, so I'm not sure how that is going to work -- possibly through an implicit type cast, which is unlikely to lead to the desired result.

Maybe you mean:

```
order by complete,
         sort_index,
         Coalesce(
           scheduled_end_time,
           starts_at,
           #{now} + INTERVAL 10 YEAR
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting NULLs last using the `-value` trick. I've added coalescing, too, as have others, which really cleans up that case statement.

```
ORDER BY 
  complete, 
  -sort_index DESC, -- Sort ascending with nulls last
  COALESCE(scheduled_end_time, starts_at, now() + INTERVAL 10 YEAR)
;
```

You can also check my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb3999/3)